"invalid argument type . cannot use boolean values in this context power apps" inside OnOkClick inside power apps canvas
I have this formula to delete 3 SharePoint items from 3 lists inside the OnOkClick inside "Enhanced component properties":-

IfError(RemoveIf(
    'Work Orders',
        ID = DashBoardGallery_1.Selected.ID
),
Notify(
    "Can not delete work order",
    NotificationType.Error
),
ForAll(varWOWOInfoDetails As wowo,
RemoveIf('Work Orders Work Order Info Details',ID=wowo.ID);
RemoveIf('Work Orders Info Details',ID=wowo.'Work Order Info Detail ID')
);
ForAll(varWOWOInfoDetails As wowo,
RemoveIf('Work Orders Info Details',ID=wowo.'Work Order Info Detail ID');
RemoveIf('Work Orders Work Order Info Details',ID=wowo.ID);
);
Notify(
    "Deleted successfully",
    NotificationType.Success
););


now on Test when i click on the delete icon, the 3 items will be removed:-

while on PROD, only items from 2 lists will be removed, so seems the items inside the "Work Orders Info Details" list will be skipped

.. although on both environments, i will get "Deleted Successfully"message.. so what could be the reason ?
Also recently i start to receive this error inside the formula ""invalid argument type . cannot use boolean values in this context power apps":-

so what is the error trying to say and is it related to the issue i am getting?
